# What is wrong with my repel player script?

Tags: python, game-engine

Based off of [another tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KdA7f421QWI), I'm trying to put together a script for an object that will apply a force to anything near it, essentially repelling it when the "near" logic brick is triggered.

```
from bge import logic

def _getForceMagnitude(distance, max_force, max_range):
    return (distance * (-max_force/max_range)) + max_force

def repel():

    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    shield = cont.owner

    for obj in scene.objects:
        vec = obj.worldPosition - shield.worldPosition
        vec.magnitude = _getForceMagnitude(vec.magnitude, 10, 4)
        vec.applyForce(vec)
```

Comment: It would help to know what's not working, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry it took a while to respond. There are no errors being reported, but I do have another script  so similar to this one to get planetary gravity. Could it be that the two are in conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked the whole script from bottom up and came up with the solution that I needed. With this script, any object that triggers the near sensor will be pushed from the origin of the object with the near sensor. The `from bge import render` and `render.drawLine(shieldLoc, objLoc, [0, 0, 255])` is just there to visually see the script when it triggers.

```
from bge import render
from bge import logic
from mathutils import Vector

def _getForceMagnitude(distance, max_force, max_range):
    return (distance * (-max_force/max_range)) + max_force

def main():
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner
    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    #sensor and sensor location
    trigger = cont.sensors["Near"]
    shieldLoc = own.worldPosition

if trigger.positive:
    #iterate through all objects in range
    obj = trigger.hitObjectList
    for objList in obj:
        #location of each object and vecter
        objLoc = objList.worldPosition
        dist = own.getDistanceTo(objLoc)
        vec = objLoc - shieldLoc
        #applying vecter
        vec.magnitude = _getForceMagnitude(dist, 50, 25)
        objList.applyForce(vec)
        render.drawLine(shieldLoc, objLoc, [0, 0, 255])
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

applyForce is only applicable to game objects.  Currently you are trying to apply force to a variable (vec) that you created.  Change the last line to

```
obj.applyForce(vec)
```

However, this will apply the force to EVERY object in the scene, not just the ones nearby which I don't believe is the behavior you want.

Also, I think you have a few issues with your script.  I made some modifications below.

You could try using the following:

```
from bge import logic

def _getForceMagnitude(distance, max_force, max_range):
    return (distance * (-max_force/max_range)) + max_force

def repel():

    scene = logic.getCurrentScene()
    cont = logic.getCurrentController()
    shield = cont.owner

    #Create reference to near sensor
    near = shield.sensors["Near"]

    #Check if near sensor is positive
    if near.positive:
        #Get the object that triggered the near sensor
        obj = near.hitObject
        #Get the distance from the object to the shield
        dist = shield.getDistanceTo(obj)

        vec = obj.worldPosition - shield.worldPosition
        vec.magnitude = _getForceMagnitude(dist, 10, 4)
        obj.applyForce(vec)
```

I'm not 100% sure what the distance variable in the _getForceMagnitude represents so I put in the distance between the shield and the object that triggers the near sensor.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Perhaps I implemented it wrong? Here is a scene with a cube falling onto a plane that should repel it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/casilne4znaedg8/test_repel.blend